# necessity of class attribute in order to position div layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, css-position

I find it difficult to understand *why* (not how) it is necessary to have a class attribute assigned to a div in order to change it's position. For example, the following code wont move the div to 200,200:

```
this.m_textLayer = document.createElement( 'div' ); 
this.m_textLayer.setAttribute( 'id', 'textLayer' ); 
this.m_textLayer.setAttribute( 'position', 'absolute' ); 
this.m_textLayer.setAttribute( 'left', '0px' ); 
this.m_textLayer.setAttribute( 'top', '0px' ); 
this.m_textLayer.setAttribute( 'width', '300px' ); 
this.m_textLayer.setAttribute( 'height', '100px' ); 
this.m_baseLayer.appendChild( this.m_textLayer );
$( '#textLayer' ).append( $( 'p' ) ).text( 'test' );
// some time later
$( '#textLayer' ).css( { left:'200px', top:'200px' } );
```

but having the 'class' attribute point to a class definition in the css with the same attributes does work as expected:

```
this.m_textLayer = document.createElement( 'div' ); 
this.m_textLayer.setAttribute( 'id', 'textLayer' ); 
this.m_textLayer.setAttribute( 'class', 'Layer' ); 
this.m_baseLayer.appendChild( this.m_textLayer );
$( '#textLayer' ).append( $( 'p' ) ).text( 'test' );
// some time later
$( '#textLayer' ).css( { left:'200px', top:'200px' } );
```

Now, I can speculate on the cause, as it probably has to do with there not being a css style defined when the class attr is not set or something, but could someone explain it to me in detail, or point me to some resource that explains precisely what actually happens here ? (I'm definitely not new to programming, but I am new to css/js/jquery and find it hard to find information on the actual mechanics of js interpretation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I find it difficult to understand why (not how) it is necessary to have a class attribute assigned to a div in order to change it's position.

It isn't. You're setting *attributes* with names like `position` and `left`, but those are not attributes, they're style properties. So change:

```
this.m_textLayer.setAttribute( 'position', 'absolute' ); 
this.m_textLayer.setAttribute( 'left', '0px' ); 
this.m_textLayer.setAttribute( 'top', '0px' ); 
this.m_textLayer.setAttribute( 'width', '300px' ); 
this.m_textLayer.setAttribute( 'height', '100px' );
```

to

```
this.m_textLayer.style.position = 'absolute' ; 
this.m_textLayer.style.left = '0px'; 
this.m_textLayer.style.top = '0px'; 
this.m_textLayer.style.width = '300px'; 
this.m_textLayer.style.height = '100px';
```

---

Side note:

Since you're using jQuery, you can do that like this as well:

```
this.m_textLayer = $( '<div>' )
                   .attr( 'id', 'textLayer' )
                   .css({
                       position: 'absolute',
                       left:     '0px',
                       top:      '0px',
                       width:    '300px',
                       height:   '100px'
                   })
                   .append( $( 'p' ) )
                   .text( 'test' )
                   .appendTo(this.m_baseLayer)[0];

// some time later
$( '#textLayer' ).css( { left:'200px', top:'200px' } );
```

Comment: oh, gosh, i feel slightly stupid here. my feeling was that the css sets attributes, but that's not the case. That certainly clears things up ! :o

Comment: Single style change: `$('#div').css('left', '10px');` and multiple style changes; `$('#div').css({'left' : '10px', 'width' : '300px'});`

Comment: Recommend this Jquery book - http://books.google.com/books/about/JavaScript_JQuery.html?id=MigLW23xdzAC

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.m_textLayer.style.position = 'absolute'; 
this.m_textLayer.style.left = '0px'; 
this.m_textLayer.style.top = '0px'; 
this.m_textLayer.style.width = '300px'; 
this.m_textLayer.style.height = '100px';
```

It does not use a class but it rather sets styles inline for the element. What you are doing is set attributes and not styles. A lot of these attributes do not exist at all so the browser would just ignore them.

The product of your code in terms of DOM looks like this:

```
<!-- Assuming m_textLayer is a DIV -->
<div position="absolute" left="0px" top="0px" width="300px" height="300px" />
```

The product of setting styles is:

```
<!-- Assuming m_textLayer is a DIV -->
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 300px; height: 300px" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing both javascript and jQuery to do the same job, not 100% sure why?

But this is not what's causing the problem, you're trying to set attributes instead of style elements.

You're currently building something like:

```
<span id="textLayer" position="absolute" left="0px" top="0px" width="300px" height="100px" />
```

Try this:

```
var m_baseLayer = document.getElementById('baselayer');
this.m_textLayer = document.createElement( 'div' ); 
this.m_textLayer.setAttribute( 'id', 'textLayer' ); 
this.m_textLayer.style.position = 'absolute' ; 
this.m_textLayer.style.left = '0px'; 
this.m_textLayer.style.top = '0px'; 
this.m_textLayer.style.width = '300px'; 
this.m_textLayer.style.height = '50px'; 
this.m_textLayer.style.background = 'green'; 
m_baseLayer.appendChild( this.m_textLayer );​
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/GPkMk/